# Is there a way to make Ehcache file based configuration override programmatic configuration?

Tags: java, ehcache

I have an application using [Ehcache 2.6](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.6). This application uses programmatic configuration of its Ehcache instances and this programmatic configuration can only be changed through code changes.

I would like to be able to tune this application using a file-based configuration. Can I introduce an ehcache.xml configuration file to the application classpath and have that file trump the programmatic configuration?

I attempted this by adding ehcache.xml and ehcache.xsd to the application on my appserver and restarting the application. It appeared to read the ehcache.xml file and initiate the cache but when I went to use my application it then appears to re-initate the cache using its programmatic configuration I got an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The myCache Cache is not alive (STATUS_UNINITIALISED)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4267)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2701)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1406)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1383)
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1348)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make something like this work. You would need at least to modify the code once to tell it to load a configuration file - and at that point, you are better off extracting all config to a file and use that afterwards.